# Export raster with its min max range from GEE 2

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, export

Following up with my previous question [Export raster with its min max range from GEE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/348655/export-raster-with-its-min-max-range-from-gee). I have tried the code below:
1.adapted from this answer [Using computed min/max image values to set min/max visualization parameters in GEE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/347480/using-computed-min-max-image-values-to-set-min-max-visualization-parameters-in-g?noredirect=1&lq=1)
Use the `.evaluate()` function to convert server-side objects to client-side objects. Include the computed min and max values in an `ee.Dictionary` object and applied the `.evaluate()` function to it. A client-side dictionary object (`dict`) is made available within the scope of the anonymous function, where the min and max values can then be referenced and set as visualization parameters.

```
var minMax = ee.Dictionary({
  minVal: stats.getNumber('NDVI_min'),
  maxVal: stats.getNumber('NDVI_max')
});

print(minMax);

minMax.evaluate(function(dict) {
  var vizParams = {
    min: dict.minVal, 
    max: dict.maxVal, 
    palette: ['green']
  };

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: maskImage.visualize(vizParams),
  description: '21072016UNDVI',
  scale: 10,
  region: table,
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',
  formatOptions: {
    cloudOptimized: true
  }
});
});
```

It is not working.
Then I tried this code:
2.adapted from this answer [Any way to have variable min and max in one visualization parameter?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/326321/any-way-to-have-variable-min-and-max-in-one-visualization-parameter).

```
var minMax = ee.Dictionary({
  minVal: stats.getNumber('NDVI_min'),
  maxVal: stats.getNumber('NDVI_max')
});

print(minMax);

minMax.evaluate(function(val) {
  var vizParams = {
    min: val.minVal, 
    max: val.maxVal, 
    palette: ['green']
  };
// Export a cloud-optimized GeoTIFF.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: maskImage.visualize(vizParams),
  description: '21072016UNDVI',
  scale: 10,
  region: table,
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',
  formatOptions: {
    cloudOptimized: true
  }
});
});
```

It is still not working....
Does it have something to do with the Nodata or null data?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the visualize function in a server-side mapping over your image collection, no need to evaluate at all. Define your min and max value and use them as arguments in the visualize function.

```
var visualizeMinMaxNDVI = function(image, region) {
  var minMax = image.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.minMax(), region, 10);
  var visParams = {
          min: minMax.getNumber('NDVI_min'),
          max: minMax.getNumber('NDVI_max'),
          };
  return image.visualize(visParams)
            .set({min: minMax.getNumber('NDVI_min'), max: minMax.getNumber('NDVI_max')});
};
```

See a full example in [this link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/49af3a856d5f19ac426ec330cd1670b2), where I included an example to export multiple images at once (as i think your are supposing to do);

Comment: Hi @Kuik thanks for your code. I don't think I can export multiple images at once because I'm looking for images on certain dates (due to tide level cloud cover ect.). When I export the image I can't use image.visualize(vizParams) any more because vizParams is an argument in the function now (am I right?). So I don't know how to use visualizeMinMaxNDVI (or NDVIvis you used in the link) as visualization parameter when exporting the image layer..

Comment: Here is the link of my code so far [link] (https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2FXuhong%2Fgeometrypoint%3ASentinel%20%2F210716%2FS210716NDVIRtest). I changed all "image,region" with "maskImage", which is the only raster layer I want. I also have another attempt which after importing into ArcGIS min change to 0 max change to 255...[link] (https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2FXuhong%2Fgeometrypoint%3ASentinel%2F210716%2FS210716NDVItest)

Comment: Just first use visualize to visualize all the images in the collection the way you want them. Then export the images you want to export. Use the "get link" button to share your code. I don't see any of your code atm.

Comment: Hi @Kuik sorry for the link. This is the one I adapted your code:https://code.earthengine.google.com/6c3ff50b93788ab92ab984b49a9e21de.

Comment: This is the one I adapted your code:https://code.earthengine.google.com/6c3ff50b93788ab92ab984b49a9e21de. Sorry it's very long I start your code from line 86. I got a bit confused when checking your link as you used "image and region". I changed it to "maskImage" since this is the only layer I'm interested in. I tried to add visualize parameter when exporting but since now the visParams is in a function I can't use it. Here is a different attempt:https://code.earthengine.google.com/96877c8f0afd56f78ce0f40571670e25. When I import this raster into ArcGIS it changed min to 0 and max to 255...

Comment: Hi @Kuik, sorry for so many comments but I'm trying to clear my confusion to solve problem. I have re-visited your link of code and I don't understand line26-29. Your NDVI are some NDVI images, as for my code I set a threshold to my NDVI (line 37) and call it "maskImage". My image is also "maskImage". If I do`var NDVIvis = maskImage.map(function(maskImage){
  return visualizeMinMaxNDVI(maskImage);
});` it shows "maskImage.map is not a function".How can I correct this bit of code? Also, how can I put visParams into "Export.image.toDrive" now (since visParams is a parameter in the function).

Comment: Hi @Kuik, I've opened a new question about this so we don't need to put more comments down here lol. Here's the link (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/349159/export-geotiff-with-pixel-min-max-value-from-gee). Thanks